# How can I use "DetectLocalizedObjects"?

Tags: .net, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to use `ImageAnnotatorClient.DetectLocalizedObjects` from the Google.Cloud.Vision.V1 API I've got a compilation error:

> 'DetectLocalizedObjects' is not a member of 'ImageAnnotationClient'

If I use `.DetectLabels` instead of `DetectLocalizedObjects` it works so I would say it is not a credential or network issue.

(Visual studio 2017, vb.net)

Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. The API version had to be 1.3.0-beta04